# MVC 6 How can I include a BaseRepository in my controller class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dapper

I am using an ORM to connect to the database it is called dapper. The issue with it is that it's database calls are synchronous and I recently found a way to make it asynchronous by following this short tutorial   http://www.joesauve.com/async-dapper-and-async-sql-connection-management/ . My question is how can I bring this BaseRepository into my Controller class ? This is the code on that website and it's the same one I have

BaseRepository- by the way there is no issue in this code

```
 public abstract class BaseRepository 
   {

private readonly string _ConnectionString;

protected BaseRepository(string connectionString) 
{
    _ConnectionString = connectionString;
}

protected async Task<T> WithConnection<T>(Func<IDbConnection, Task<T>> getData) 
{
    try {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_ConnectionString)) {
            await connection.OpenAsync(); // Asynchronously open a connection to the database
            return await getData(connection); // Asynchronously execute getData, which has been passed in as a Func<IDBConnection, Task<T>>
        }
    }
    catch (TimeoutException ex) {
        throw new Exception(String.Format("{0}.WithConnection() experienced a SQL timeout", GetType().FullName), ex);
    }
    catch (SqlException ex) {
        throw new Exception(String.Format("{0}.WithConnection() experienced a SQL exception (not a timeout)", GetType().FullName), ex);
    }
}
```

}

and now he brings it in like this

```
public class PersonRepository : BaseRepository
{
    public PersonRepository(string connectionString): base (connectionString) { }

    public async Task<Person> GetPersonById(Guid Id)
    {
        return await WithConnection(async c => {

            // Here's all the same data access code,
            // albeit now it's async, and nicely wrapped
            // in this handy WithConnection() call.
            var p = new DynamicParameters();
            p.Add("Id", Id, DbType.Guid);
            var people = await c.QueryAsync<Person>(
                sql: "sp_Person_GetById", 
                param: p, 
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return people.FirstOrDefault();

        });
    }
}
```

The part I am having a problem with is this **public class PersonRepository : BaseRepository** because Asp.Net Controllers start with **public class HomeController: Controller** , I need access to the **WithConnection** method to get this working. My controller looks like this

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public class ConnectionRepository : BaseRepository
        {
            public ConnectionRepository(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }

        }
      public async Task<ActionResult> topfive()
            {
    // I get Error on WithConnection as it can't see the BaseRepository
                return await WithConnection(async c =>
                {


                    var topfive = await c.QueryAsync<Streams>("select * from streams ").ToList();
                return View(topfive);
                });

 }
            }
```

I obviously can not cover my ActionResult method with the BaseRepository because it gives all types of errors any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using inheritance instead of composition? What about something like:

```
public class PersonRepository : BaseRepository
{
    public PersonRepository(string connectionString): base (connectionString) { }

    public async Task<Person> GetPersonById(Guid Id)
    {
        return await WithConnection(async c => {

            // Here's all the same data access code,
            // albeit now it's async, and nicely wrapped
            // in this handy WithConnection() call.
            var p = new DynamicParameters();
            p.Add("Id", Id, DbType.Guid);
            var people = await c.QueryAsync<Person>(
                sql: "sp_Person_GetById", 
                param: p, 
                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            return people.FirstOrDefault();

        });
    }
    }

        public class ConnectionRepository : BaseRepository
        {
            public ConnectionRepository(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) { }

        }
      public async Task<List<TopFileClass>> topfive()
            {
    // I get Error on WithConnection as it can't see the BaseRepository
                return await WithConnection(async c =>
                {


                    var topfive = await c.QueryAsync<Streams>("select * from streams ").ToList();
                return topfive;
                });

 }

public class HomeController : Controller
{
   private readonly PersonRepository _repo;

   public HomeController(PersonRepository repo)
   {
       _repo = repo;
   }

   public async Task<ActionResult> TopFive() 
   {
       var top5 = await _repo.topfive();
       return View(top5);
   }
}
```

If you are not familiar how to make the repository automatically get injected into the constructor, read up on dependency injection in MVC 6.

Answer (score 1):

you have to intehirt the "BaseRepository" from "Controller". i think that will work for you. then just go with below code:

```
public abstract class BaseRepository : Controller 
{ 
// do you work
}


public class PersonRepository : BaseRepository
{
public PersonRepository(string connectionString): base (connectionString) { }

public async Task<Person> GetPersonById(Guid Id)
{
    return await WithConnection(async c => {

        // Here's all the same data access code,
        // albeit now it's async, and nicely wrapped
        // in this handy WithConnection() call.
        var p = new DynamicParameters();
        p.Add("Id", Id, DbType.Guid);
        var people = await c.QueryAsync<Person>(
            sql: "sp_Person_GetById", 
            param: p, 
            commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        return people.FirstOrDefault();

    });
   }
}
```